# Creating a list/vector from first column od multiple data

Tags: r

In total I have 21 csv files which I would like to load to R. So I did:

```
list_of_data = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
tbl_met = lapply(list_of_data, read.csv)
```

Can't give you the `dput` because it's too much data...

What I want to do is to get a list off all names in first column in all datasets. Combined to one vector/list but there are 2 problems:

- first of all the columns in those files are separated by ";" or without any separation mark... Do I have to look inside those files and make them all separated in the same way ?
- second problem is that there might be duplicates of names and I'd like to remove them from the list.

Do you have any idea how to do that ? Should I provide you some more data ? If yes, let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Probably it's not the easiest one but it works.
First of all I had to convert all of the csv files to the same pattern. Easy task with R.

Later:

```
list_of_data = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
tbl_met = lapply(list_of_data, read.csv)
tbl <- rbindlist(tbl_met) ## binding all of the tables in the list by row

vec_names <- tbl$locus ## name of the column with names which I am interested in
vec <- unique(vec_names) ## removing the duplicates
```

Nicely done!

Comment: Good job. Thanks for posting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little sceptical about the fact that in some files there are no separation marks. How would you separate the columns? Are all the column names the same at least?

But can you try this and see if it gives anything?

```
library(data.table)
list_of_data = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
tbl_met = lapply(list_of_data, fread)
DT=rbindlist(l=tbl_met,use.names = FALSE);
print(unique(DT[,1,with=FALSE]))
```

Thanks

Comment: `> DT=rbindlist(tbl_met,use.names = FALSE);
Error in rbindlist(tbl_met, use.names = FALSE) : 
  unused argument (use.names = FALSE)` That's the error which appears. For some tables I can just use this code to load it `read.csv ("table.csv")` but for others I need separation mark like `sep=";"`. That's if I want to load them separately...

Comment: I have edited the answer, but I am not sure it will work. How do you tackle the lack of separation marks?

Comment: Still the same error. I just load the tables like I showed you in the comment. They are separated in the `csv` files. I will just manually change in the files to add a separation mark between the columns. Than it should be easy, right ?